# In Gtk#, why might VALID_ITER fail even after I check it with IterIsValid?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#, gtktreeview

I have a convenience function in my `TreeView` that looks something like this:

```
Card GetCardFromPath (TreePath path)
{
    TreeIter iter;
    if (path == null || !Model.GetIter (out iter, path))
        return null;

    if ((Model as TreeModelSort).IterIsValid (iter))
        return (Card) Model.GetValue (iter, 0);

    return null;
}
```

Most of the time this works without any errors. But when it is called directly after the Model is changed, line 8 gives me these Gtk runtime errors:

```
[Fatal 16:53:02.448] [Gtk] gtk_list_store_get_value: assertion `VALID_ITER (iter, list_store)' failed
[Fatal 16:53:02.449] [GLib-GObject] g_value_unset: assertion `G_IS_VALUE (value)' failed
```

As far as I can tell, I shouldn't even need to check `IterIsValid`, because I'm already checking the return value of `Model.GetIter`. Even so, how can `VALID_ITER` fail in a function that only gets called if `IterIsValid` returns `true`?

If it makes a difference, the Model is a `TreeModelSort`, which sorts a `TreeModelFilter`, which filters a `ListStore`. The error occurs when `GetCardFromPath` is called from `HandleSelectionChanged` when multiple rows have just been removed from the ListStore. It doesn't seem to prevent anything from working properly, but having a cascade of errors whenever I remove multiple rows isn't really ideal.

Comment: Could you clarify 'after the Model is changed'? Do you replace the ListStore or modify its contents? If you do replace, you will need to reattach the TreeModelSort too.